# Grails - How to modify list items from g:select dynamically

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I have a domain class called `Client` with typical attributes (`name, surname,` and so on).

There's also a class called `PaymentConditions` (which establishes some parameters to calculate the amount that a client has to pay) which have a reference to `Client`. A `Client` can have many `PaymentConditions`.

And finally there's a `Payment` class with attributes like `paymentDate`, `amount` and a reference to `Client` and `PaymentConditions`.

When I want to register a `Payment` I use an Ajax call to retrieve data from the `Client` (including the client id) that is making the payment. But the problem is that because of the reference to `PaymentConditions` there's a drop-down list with all the payment conditions registered. What I need is to filter the drop-down list items to show only the ones that are related to the retrieved `client`.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED:** There's an input field in the form where the user has to enter the Client's surname. This input field has implemented the JQuery UI autocomplete feature, so when a Client is selected the PaymentConditions drop-down list must be updated or filtered for the retrieved Client.

Comment: How are you populating the `PaymentConditions` list? I'd use something like: `def client = Client.get(id); def paymentConditions = client.paymentConditions`...

Comment: I'm using the automatically generated view code: `<g:select id="paymentCondition" name="paymentCondition.id" from="${PaymentCondition.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${paymentInstance?.paymentCondition?.id}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>`. I need this list filtered after the Ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

For showing dropdown list grails provides a special select tag-

```
<g:select name="paymentCondition"               //Name you want to send back to server
      from="${client.paymentConditions}"        //Client wise filtered conditions where client is a passed client instance
      value="${client.paymentConditions.id}"    //Selected option value to send to server
/>
```

Or if you want to filter the list out in controller only then you can do-

```
def client = Client.get(id); 
def paymentConditions = client.paymentConditions
```

Use the way you like according to your implementation. Hope it helps.

Comment: They seem interesting but I think they won't solve my problem. I'm using the automatically generated code: `<g:select id="paymentCondition" name="paymentCondition.id" from="${PaymentCondition.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${paymentInstance?.paymentCondition?.id}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>`, so after create page is rendered I have a list with all payment conditions registered. I need to filter the drop-down list after the Ajax call (which retrieves Client data) is completed.

Comment: Ok so in that case you will have to get the filtered list with your AJAX call. Explanation- The `<g:select></g:select>` tags work on the server before the content is delivered to the client and client gets html select tag, so you cant change it after AJAX call. Only option left is work out your filtered list in controller and send it with AJAX and update the list using JavaScript with onsuccess method of AJAX.

Comment: I think it would work. But that's precisely what I don't know how to do. I already have a closure to generate a drop-down list given a Client id: `render g.select(name: "paymentCondition.id",id: "paymentCondition",from: conditions,optionKey: "id",value: "${payment?.paymentCondition?.id}",class: "many-to-one")`. But it produces an error on `value`. And my main problem is that I don't know how to replace an specific drop-down list with an AJAX generated one.